# UIActivityViewController remove bottom part

Tags: ios, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller

Is there anyway to remove the bottom part from UIActivityViewController?

also - Is there anyway to remove the MORE icon from UIActivityViewController?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In **iOS 8.2**, `UIActivityViewController` shows only a single row for `UIActivityCategoryShare` activity types if we do not provide any custom `UIActivity`.

In **iOS 8.3** onwards, `UIActivityViewController` shows two lines whether you provide your own custom `UIActivity` or not.

Below are the screenshots for both:

**For iOS 8.2**

[image]

**For iOS 9.0**

[image]

This is how Apple has designed the `UIActivityViewController`. You can provide custom functions but not custom user interface in `UIActivityViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible to remove the bottom part .... However we can remove the unwanted icons using excludedActivityTypes property of UIActivityViewController object. Try this

```
 UIActivityViewController *vc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
 vc.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,UIActivityTypeMail];
```

Comment: why my answer delete? my answer is different from your answer.check my answer and i have 2 upvote. my answer is helpful.so please undelete my answer